# Why is the animation for MapView.Marker in my react native view not working?

Tags: react-native

I have created a mapview and some markers using MapView.Marker. I am switching between the markers using scroll view. The switch is working fine, centering the current marker.

Also I created some animation when the user switches to the current marker. I used interpolations for that (opacity and scale). However the **animations are not working**. I am testing now on Android. Here is my code :

```
   const interpolations = this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
          const inputRange = [
            (index - 1) * CARD_WIDTH,
            index * CARD_WIDTH,
            ((index + 1) * CARD_WIDTH),
          ];
          const scale = this.animation.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [1, 2.5, 1],
            extrapolate: "clamp",
          });
          const opacity = this.animation.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [0.35, 1, 0.35],
            extrapolate: "clamp",
          });
          return { scale, opacity };
        });

        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
              ref={map => this.map = map}
              initialRegion={this.state.region}
              style={styles.container}
            >
              {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
                const scaleStyle = {
                  transform: [
                    {
                      scale: interpolations[index].scale,
                    },
                  ],
                };
                const opacityStyle = {
                  opacity: interpolations[index].opacity,
                };
                return (
                  <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate= {{latitude: marker.location.coordinates[0], longitude: marker.location.coordinates[1]}}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap,opacityStyle]}>
                      <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                      <View style={styles.marker} />
                    </Animated.View>
                  </MapView.Marker>
                );
              })}
            </MapView>


  markerWrap: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 17,
    borderWidth: 2,
    overflow: "hidden",
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    borderColor: "rgba(130,4,150, 0.5)",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(130,4,150, 0.3)",
    position: "absolute",
  },
  marker: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(130,4,150, 0.9)"
  },
  ring: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,


  },
```

Please let know your suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wrapper I made for `<MapView.Marker />`

**Wrapper**

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useEffect, ReactNode } from 

'react';
import { Animated, ViewStyle, View } from 'react-native';

interface AnimatedMarkerProp {
  size?: number;
  children: ReactNode;
  showAnimation?: boolean;
  containerStyle?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
  animatedViewStyle?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
  childrenWrapperStyle?: ViewStyle | ViewStyle[];
}

/**
 *
 * @param size defines the height, width & borderRadius of each view. The container View will plus 20px (animation area).
 * @param showAnimation start or stop the animation.
 * @param containerStyle styles for container view. (1st)
 * @param animatedViewStyle styles for the animated view. (2nd)
 * @param childrenWrapperStyle styles for the animated view containing the children. (3rd)
 * @returns An animated wrapper for markers.
 */

const PulseAnimation = ({
  size,
  showAnimation,
  children,
  containerStyle,
  animatedViewStyle,
  childrenWrapperStyle,
}: AnimatedMarkerProp) => {
  const fadeAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const pulseAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const animationArea = 20;

  const startAnimation = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.timing(pulseAnimation, {
            delay: 250,
            toValue: showAnimation ? 1.5 : 1,
            duration: 750,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }),
          Animated.timing(pulseAnimation, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 750,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }),
          Animated.timing(pulseAnimation, {
            toValue: showAnimation ? 1.5 : 1,
            duration: 250,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }),
          Animated.timing(fadeAnimation, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 1000,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }),
        ])
      ),
    ]).start();
  }, [fadeAnimation, pulseAnimation, showAnimation]);

  const stopAnimation = useCallback(() => {
    pulseAnimation.stopAnimation(() => {
      pulseAnimation.setValue(1);
    });
    fadeAnimation.stopAnimation();
  }, [fadeAnimation, pulseAnimation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAnimation) {
      startAnimation();
    } else {
      stopAnimation();
    }
  }, [showAnimation, startAnimation, stopAnimation]);

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        !!size && {
          height: size + animationArea,
          width: size + animationArea,
          borderRadius: (size + animationArea) / 2,
        },
        {
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        containerStyle,
      ]}
    >
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          !!size && { height: size, width: size, borderRadius: size / 2 },
          {
            transform: [
              {
                scale: pulseAnimation,
              },
            ],
            backgroundColor: fadeAnimation.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [
                'rgba(41, 182, 246, 0)',
                'rgba(41, 182, 246, 0.30)',
              ],
            }),
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
          animatedViewStyle,
        ]}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            !!size && { height: size, width: size, borderRadius: size / 2 },
            {
              transform: [
                {
                  scale: pulseAnimation.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [1, 1.5],
                    outputRange: [1, 0.67],
                    extrapolate: 'clamp',
                  }),
                },
              ],
            },
            childrenWrapperStyle,
          ]}
        >
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PulseAnimation;
```

**Usage**

```
<Marker
        id="userMarker"
        anchor={anchor}
        coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
        zIndex={105}
        onPress={onPressMarker}
        hitSlop={hitSlop}
      >
        <PulseAnimation
          size={32}
          showAnimation={userMarkerSelected}
          animatedViewStyle={[styles.pinShadow]}
          childrenWrapperStyle={styles.pinBg}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              transform: [
                {
                  rotate: mapIsRotating ? '0deg' : anglePlusMap,
                },
              ],
            }}
          >
            <UserPointerIcon />
          </Animated.View>
        </PulseAnimation>
      </Marker>
```

In this case of usage, the children component also had to be animated.

[Animation](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExZmhhNTdnbmR4Y2hlY24yYnMzdjA2MmJ0MG9vNThqdzF2eTRxazhyeiZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/aBtqvx7qKqzPCVUkn1/giphy.gif)

Comment: `Animated.parallel([])` is not required here hehe sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue. The following was added in the official docs 3 years ago-

**Issue:** Since android needs to render its marker views as a bitmap, the animations APIs may not be compatible with the Marker views. Not sure if this can be worked around yet or not.

You can find it here-https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps,
under the 'Using the MapView with the Animated API' section.